# DB2 An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "LIST TABLES"

Tags: db2

I am a first time DB2 user, have trouble in executing "list tables;" in IBM Data Studio.

I can run "select" commands (end with semicolon) and "update commands" but "list tables;" (both with and without semicolon) gives following error:

```
An unexpected token "END-OF-STATEMENT" was found following "LIST TABLES". 
Expected tokens may include:  "JOIN <joined_table>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.14.113
```

Update: Alternatively, the following command works:

```
select tabname from syscat.tables where tabschema = 'whatever-schema-name';
```

BTW, is it possible to change the default query result window from "Status" to "Result1". It is in "Status" window by default and every time I have to click "Result1" tab to see the query result.

Answer (score 1):

The "list table" command is a db2 cli command. But you can query syscat.tables in data studio or other type of data connections.

```
SELECT * FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what I am going to say, but Data Studio is only for SQL commands. List table command is not a DDL, DML nor DCL, and for this reason, you cannot execute that command from the SQL editor in Data Studio. Those commands are for the CLP.

Answer (score 0):

use list all the tables in the DB as given below

```
    db2 list tables for all
```

use list all the tables in the Schema as given below

```
    db2 list tables for schema scheme_Name
```